# Switch between views using a Tabbar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I have an iOS application with a Tab Bar, and two subview. My first view is a Table View. 
So, I want to switch to the second view when I click on a cell of the first view, and keep the TabBar visible. 
When I do that using "Show" segue in the storyboard, I lost the TabBar. 
And when I do it in my TableViewController with the following code, the second view is not loading.

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = mySecondViewController
```

That only select the second element in the TabBar, but didn't display him.

Anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix my problem. I've originally put the line of code bellow on the viewDidLoad() of my controller :
`tabBarController.selectedViewController = mySecondViewController`

After moving this line in a different methode, call by a simple button, that worked...

Answer (score 0):

try using index of UITabBar item to switch, like this:

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1
```

The problem also may be because you try to set View to selectedViewController, where uiviewcontroller should be. It is hard to say, because of lack of information.

Comment: I've forget to make a precision, mySecondView refers to a controller. I've edit my post to make the precision. And I've still the same problem when I use selectedIndex method.

Comment: please, check if your tabBarController.viewControllers contains anything

Comment: Yep, it contains my two views.

Answer (score 0):

In the story board make sure you control drag from the tab bar controller to your view controller and click "Relationship Segue: View Controller"

Comment: Yes, segues are correct. Except for the segue I use from first view (the table view) to the second, who are a show segue. But I didn't have any other choice for switch to the second view from the first table view).